# PDFBox convert PDF to TIFF. Reduce image size in bytes

Tags: java, image, pdf, tiff, pdfbox

I'm trying to convert a pdf to a tiff image. I got it working by using pdfbox but the image is too big.

Let's say my PDF size is 224kb => image size=1.4Mb

How can I make the tiff file smaller without losing quality?

Here is some of the code:

```
TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
writer = tiffspi.createWriterInstance();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
TIFFImageWriteParam param2 = (TIFFImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param2.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

param2.setCompressionType("LZW");
param2.setCompressionQuality(1.0f);

writer.setOutput(output);
writer.write(null,new IIOImage(image,null,null),param2);
```

Comment: *"How can I make the tiff file smaller without losing quality?"*  Magic?

Comment: But isn't it possible to make it smaller with some setting or is it normal that this tiff files is that big when the pdf is small?

Comment: A direct image will (99% of the time) be bigger than the equivalent PDF.  The thing is, much of what you see in a PDF is generated from some text with associated styles, fonts and positioning parameters (often also expressed in text).  When it comes to the image OTOH, all that text has been rendered to glyphs (that are probably anti-aliased - which pushes the file size up even further).  What is the purpose of reducing a 'text searchable' PDF to a plain old image anyway?  ***As much as I despise the PDF format, I cannot see the sense of transforming a PDF to a static image.***

Comment: What format is the image, and why not simply extract it directly from the PDF?

Comment: The pdf that I try to convert is a pdf with a page filled with one image, that i get from a scanning partner. The printing partner requests a tiff to print, so i need to convert the pdf to tiff.

Comment: when i try to extract the image with pdfbox like this:
PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
                PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                Map images = resources.getImages();

and i debug this images has size 0

Comment: Please supply the PDF for inspection.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some guidelines:

- Match the colours to your output. If you are rendering in black and
  white use bi-value output, which translates to one bit per pixel.  If
  you have few colours without too much shading or mixing like
  highlight colouring or cartoon-style graphics, use 256 colours.  Only
  use full colour if you have photographs in your PDF.  If you have to
  produce full colour, your quest for smallness is doomed.
- Match your compression to your colour depth.  For monochrome use
  CCITT T.4 or CCITT T.6, which are way more efficient for
  bit-sequences.  LZW works best on byte-sequences such as 256-colour. 
  If you have to produce full colour, your only hope of decent
  compression is jpeg, but this will fuzz your text and lines.